# Why are Controller methods like RedirectToAction() and HttpNotFound() protected internal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement a service pattern to provide some logic for several of my ASP.NET MVC controllers.  Depending on the result of the logic, I may want the controllers to redirect, or give a 404 not found, or various other responses.  Therefore I want my controllers to be able to receive an `out ActionResult` parameter from the service method(s) that they can return to carry out these responses.

The trouble is that I don't see any way for the service to generate `ActionResult`s.  Because methods like `RedirectToAction()` and `HttpNotFound()` in the `Controller` class are set to `protected internal`, they cannot be accessed from the service class.

What is the rationale behind making them `protected internal`?  How is my service supposed to indicate to the controllers what action result they should return?

An example of what I might want to do is allow the user, in several places, to set a configuration variable if they have permission.  The controller code would look something like:

```
public ActionResult SetVariable(int variableId, int variableValue) {
    ActionResult actionRes;
    _svcVars.SetVariable(variableId, variableValue, out actionRes);
    return actionRes;
}
```

... and the service code would look something like:

```
public bool SetVariable(int variableId, int variableValue, out ActionResult actionRes) {
    ConfigRepository repoConfig = new ConfigRepository();
    if (!repoConfig.VariableExists(variableId)) {
        actionRes = HttpNotFound("Could not find config variable");
        return false;
    }

    if (!repoConfig.VariableMayBeChanged(variableId)) {
        actionRes = Redirect("/ChangeForbidden.html");
        return false;
    }

    int variablesListId = repoConfig.SetVariable(variableId, variableValue);
    actionRes = RedirectToAction("ViewVariablesList", new { listId = variablesListId });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further using a code example and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The trouble is that I don't see any way for the service to generate ActionResults.

As with any object in .NET you could use its constructor in order to create an instance.

Just like that:

```
var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new 
{
    action = "ViewVariablesList",
    listId = variablesListId
});
actionRes = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
```

As far as why the corresponding methods on the Controller class are protected and internal, well, a question that you could address to the people designing the framework.

Comment: Bizarre that those protected internal methods just seem to instantiate the object and do pretty much nothing else.  Are they there just so the code "looks nicer" by not having a `new` in it?

Comment: Yes, exactly, they are just to make the code look shorter inside the controllers.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that there isn't a `RedirectToActionResult` so I guess that method does some under-the-cover work to generate a `RedirectToRouteResult`.

Comment: Yes, precisely. That's why I used `RedirectToRouteResult` in my answer.

Comment: Is your example code the equivalent of saying (in a Controller): `RedirectToAction("ViewVariablesList", new { listId = variablesListId });`?